# Transfer winform data to yahoo login page inside Chrome browser

Tags: winforms, google-chrome, c#-2.0, winforms-to-web

My Winform contails

**Two TextBoxes**

**1)txtUserName**

**2)txtPassword**

and **1 Button object**

**1)btnLogin**

I just want to transfer winform txtUserName and txtPassword data to My Yahoo login page while click on btnLogin.

I achived this thing for IE but now I want to do for other Web Browser like Chrome

I search it on google but i didnt get any help for this. please if you know how to do this so please guide me.

Thankx in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my issue after spending long time over it.
This code open the chrome browser and transfer your winform data to chrome browser.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace WindowsFormsChrome
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // download the chrome driver
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\Downloads\chromedriver"); 
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.yahoo.com");
            IWebElement myField = driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtUserName"));
            myField.SendKeys("UserName");
            IWebElement myField = driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtPassword"));
            myField.SendKeys("Password");
            IWebElement myField = driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnLogin"));
            myField.click()
        }
     }
}
```

if you want to transfer tour data to other browser you just change the driver for respecctive browser i will work.